# How to send HTTP POST request with body in VBA

Tags: python, vba, http

Im trying to send a post request using vba and struggling to convert my python code to vba.
In python I can do this

```
import requests

headers = {
        "authority": "platform.example.com",
        "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    }

data = "{"messages":[{"to":"12345","channel":"sms","content":"Test message"}]}"

r=requests.post("https://example.com/v1/message", headers=headers, data=data)
```

I have tried this in vba but no luck. Msgbox comes up blank

```
Sub test()

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
Url = "https://example.com/v1/message"
objHTTP.Open "POST", Url, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "authority", "platform.example.com",
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/json"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "sec-fetch-site", "same-site"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "sec-fetch-mode", "cors"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "sec-fetch-dest", "empty"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.9"

Data = """messages=[{'to':'1234','channel':'sms','content':'Test message'}]"""


objHTTP.send Data
MsgBox objHTTP.ResponseText

End Sub
```

How can I get the vba working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with double-quotes to replicate the `Data` that works:

```
Data = "{""messages"":[{""to"":""1234"",""channel"":""sms"",""content"":""Test message""}]}"
```

Comment: I just tried but still getting 403 error.

Comment: I notice you use `CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")`. I always set a reference to _Microsoft XML, v6.0_ and then use `Dim XmlHttp As XMLHTTP60` and `Set XmlHttp = New XMLHTTP60`.

Comment: I retried and it worked, not sure why didnt work before, thanks!